# PHP POST does not redirect properly

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

I have two different sites and want to pass data via a form from the first to the second page.
The form looks as follows (simplified):

```
<form method="POST" action="https://othersite.me/login.php">
    <label class="title">
        E-Mail
    </label>
    <input name="luser" type="email">
    <label class="title">
        Password
    </label>
    <input name="lpasswd" type="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

The php code othersite.me/login.php looks as follows:

```
<?php
    $email=Format::input($_POST['luser']?:$_GET['e']);
    $passwd=Format::input($_POST['lpasswd']?:$_GET['t']);
?>

<form method="POST" action="login.php">
    <label class="title">
        E-Mail
    </label>
    <input name="luser" type="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
    <label class="title">
        Password
    </label>
    <input type="password" value="<?php echo $passwd; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now I expect that when I enter some data on the first page, the data is transferred to otherpage.me/login.php and displayed in the appropriate fields.

Curiously, after pressing the submit button, the website is redirected to othersite.me/login.php for less than a second and then automatically to othersite.me/index.php.

If I use GET instead of POST, the form works as expected and stays on othersite.me/login.php.

How is this possible and how can I fix that. Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need two php file to do this? You can use `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` in your login.php and start processing the submitted data there. You can follow this [instruction](https://html.form.guide/php-form/php-form-action-self/)

Comment: Thanks mate, of course I could do that. But unfortunately these two sites already exist on different hosts and my requirement is to link them together. This behaviour is so weird. Why is GET working as expected, but POST redirects me one step further?

Comment: Must be because of the routing in your second php file. Have you check it?

Comment: That was the hint i was looking for. Thank you so much. I've found a misconfigured route. I'll accept your answer, because your routing hint in the comments section has led to success.

Comment: @CLRW97, glad to help you mate! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation to comment yet so I will answer.

In the othersite.me/login.php if you have permission paste the code below
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`
This will return all warnings and fatal errors

Comment: I've added the the code, but no errors are displayed because of the redirection to the .../index.php. If I change to GET and add wrong credentials, errors are displayed -> I added it correctly.